# What is Deep Supervision?

Tags: deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

I am relatively new to deep learning and currently working in biomedical applications of deeply networking. I came across this term "Deep Supervision" in few papers like here

> UNet++: A Nested U-Net Architecture for Medical Image Segmentation

I tried searching but I can't understand the meaning of this term. Can somebody explain it to me?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its related to software engineering

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/